# Determine Exact Upload Speed?

Tags: c#, wpf, file-upload

I wanted to check the upload speed of the system.

```
void CheckUploadSpeed()
{
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    {
        IPv4InterfaceStatistics ipis = networkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics();
        BytesSentb4Upload = ipis.BytesSent;
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(string.Format("{0}speedtext.txt", path)); //speedtext.txt is a 5 MB file.
        var fileBytes = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        stream.Close();
        startTime = Environment.TickCount; 
        wc.UploadDataAsync(new Uri("http://www.example.com/"), fileBytes);
        InternetSpeedResult = "Data upload started. Uploading 5MB file";
        wc.UploadProgressChanged += new UploadProgressChangedEventHandler(UploadProgressCallback);
        wc.UploadDataCompleted += wc_UploadDataCompleted;
    }
}
```

### And on `Upload Progress Changed`

```
void UploadProgressCallback(object sender, UploadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    InternetSpeedResult = string.Format("Checking Upload Speed ... ");
    double endTime = Environment.TickCount; 
    double secs = Math.Round(Math.Floor(endTime - startTime) / 1000, 0); 
    if (secs >= 30) 
    { 
        UploadComplete(sender, e); 
    }
}
```

This code actually is serving my issue but the problem is that this is **not giving the exact results everytime**. Since I am counting on Complete `BytesSent` in the particular period of time. This numbers automatically varies. If the Speed is very low (less than 512 KBPS) and very high (Greater than 20 MBPS) than its not giving the expected upload rate.

1. What should I be doing in the code that I can rely on the Results?
2. Is there any other approach to check the Upload Speed
3. If the Speed is very low (less than 512 KBPS) and very high (Greater than 20 MBPS). What approach should I take?

Comment: How do you know what the results are not accurate? What are you comparing them to?

Comment: @GlenThomas I am comparing it with Speedtest.net

Comment: 1MB is not much to upload on a fast connection. I would try increasing that. The chunk size will make a big difference too.

Comment: @GlenThomas Sorry I have updated the code. The file size is 5MB. Yet the problem is if the speed is higher even 5MB is not going to give exact results. and If the speed is slow it take ages to conclude the Upload Speed. That too is not Exact.

Comment: Well the solution would be to upload for a set time, not a set data size. Instead of uploading 5MB of data, upload data for 2 minutes.

Comment: The real upload and download speed depends on the chunk size, the thruput of your clients framework, the thruput of the servers framework and all network components between you and the server. Can you tell me the difference between the expected upload rate and the measured upload rate of your application?

Comment: Well you have a valid point. The expected upload rate would be 4.5-4.9 MBPS and Measured upload rate would vary everytime. Sometimes the output is 3.5, Sometimes 4.5 and Sometimes even higher and lower. I am not able to rely on the code.

Comment: Yes @GlenThomas and thus in my `UploadProgress` event I have implemented `double endTime = Environment.TickCount;
            double secs = Math.Round(Math.Floor(endTime - startTime) / 1000, 0);
            if (secs >= 30)
            {
                UploadComplete(sender, e);
            }`
That actually solves the issue for Lower Upload Speed. But not for higher one.

Comment: Serious speed tests use several chunks of data. For example

1. 128kb 
2. 256kb
3. 512kb
4. 1mb
5. 2mb
6. 4mb
7. 8mb
8. 16mb

and and and.. 

At some chunk size, the speed doesn't change anymore. You can declare this speed measurement as accurate for the specific network connection between yourself and the webserver. 

The next step is to use more servers and calculate the average speed between the servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say this as a solution whereas it would be small workaround which might help you to get rely on your upload speed.

**Increase the size** of the uploaded file to somewhere around **100MB** or so.
Set the **`secs >= 60`**

Now whatever the speed of the network is if it low it would check for a minute and let u know the upload speed. If it is higher. Then also it would let u know either all 100 MB is transferred and you will get the upload speed and if not than you you'll get to know the speed in 60 seconds.

Since working with high speed internet the problem is that the bandwidth is not optimum while the transaction begins. as soon as you start sending or receiving data it will increase the speed thus Changing it to 60 seconds and increasing the file size will give you results in both the cases.